# Storing ordered images the sidebar of a Wordpress theme

Tags: content-management-system, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am creating a Wordpress theme for a client. Part of the design is to fill the unused space at the bottom of the sidebar with a collection of images. She'd like to be able to manage the images using the Wordpress admin. That means adding, deleting, and reordering.

I don't work with Wordpress much. Is there a quick, dirty, and effective way to accomplish this that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would suggest using the [NextGEN Gallery plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/) to achieve this.

you can create a specific gallery for the theme (includes management, adding images, and deleting images) and then add this code where you want it in the theme: `echo do_shortcode('[nggallery id=x]');`

Comment: This has turned out to be a great solution to this problem. Thanks +1